# Delay a JQuery click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is driving me crazy.  I'm trying to apply a listener to a div so that when it is clicked it shows a custom drag-down menu (another div).  This is how I am trying to get this done in JQuery:

```
$('#fakeFont').click(function(){
    $('#fontSelect').removeClass('hidden');
    $('html').one('click', function(){
        $('#fontselect').addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

The problem is that the listener I'm applying to the html is recognizing the first click.  Thanks in advance to anybody knows how to remedy this.

Comment: @Evan `one` is a method. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping propagation:

```
$('#fakeFont').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#fontSelect').removeClass('hidden');
    $('html').one('click', function(){
        $('#fontselect').addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```